# Generating a consistent schema definition for large API responses when calling a REST API from a GraphQL server

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, openapi, amadeus

What is the best way to generate a consistent schema definition for large API responses when calling a REST API from a GraphQL server?

I am building a GraphQL server and am trying to call a REST API in order to retrieve data for my GraphQL queries. The response from the API can be quite large, and I want to ensure that the schema definition for the API responses is consistent in order to properly handle the data in my GraphQL server. Is there a recommended way to do this, such as using an OpenAPI specification or any other method? Are there any tools or libraries that are particularly helpful for this task, particularly when dealing with large amounts of data?

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: By "large responses" do you mean the actual data in the fields? So for example if you're returning a base64 encoded image that is a couple hundred K you would prefer not to have that super long string in your schema example, correct?

Comment: By "large responses," I mean responses that are very long and would take a significant amount of time to create manually.

Comment: Sure, OpenAPI or JSON-Schema as a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how accurate you want your schema to be.  The data is generally stored in the exmple field, so in my case where I'm returning base64 encoded images, I made sure the example was as small, and valid, as it could be (in this case it's a 1 pixel GIF). This will work for automated testing and forms generation.

```
"properties" :{
  "socialimage": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "image",
    "example": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAIBRAA7",
    "minLength": 0,
    "maxLength": 255
  }
```

But it's also acceptable to provide a truncated example so long as you understand, and make it clear, that it's not a **functional** example and shouldn't be used as mock data for testing or rendering

```
  "properties" : {   
     "socialimage": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "image",
        "example": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAI...",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
      }
     }
  "description": "Data used for blog pages. Note the socialimg example is truncated"
  }
```